# Mandar un dato a un script en matlab

Tags: matlab

Tengo este codigo en matlab el cual creo un scripts pero tengo que mandarle un dato al momento en el que se crea tengo que madar el  resultado del la suma al scripts que he creado

```
diary ('NuevoScript.m')
a=5;
b=6;
res=5+6;

diary off
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Que hace ese script? Podría ser una función en otro script, con lo que no tendrías ningún problema para pasarle datos. El script sería algo así

```
function NuevoScript(suma)
    %%Lo que quieras hacer con ella
end
```

Y le podrías llamar facilmente:

```
a=5;
b=6;
res=5+6;
NuevoScript(res)
```